# Phonegap 3.5 (not Cordova) icons specified in config.xml NOT copied during build

Tags: cordova

I'm using the newly released PhoneGap 3.5.0-0.20.4 release.

The documentation clearly states ([here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens)) that I should be able to put the following in my config.xml and that the paths provided are relative to the project's www folder:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
</platform>
```

However, when I do this and then run: phonegap local build ios, the copy fails and the message indicates that it's looking in the wrong place. Such as:

cp: no such file or directory: /Users/John/Documents/MyProjects/WorkFlow/res/ios/icon-72.png

cp: no such file or directory: /Users/John/Documents/MyProjects/WorkFlow/res/ios/icon-72@2x.png

To add to the mystery, if I really do put the files in the location mentioned in the error message, that doesn't work either.

So far, I've had to revert to manually putting the icons in iOS-specific project's Resources/icons folder: /Users/John/Documents/MyProjects/WorkFlow/platforms/ios/Work Flow/Resources/icons

But I'd really like to declare them the way it's documented.

Anyone gotten this to work with PhoneGap 3.* ?

Comment: I'm not positive, but could the problem be the leading `/` in the path? Try removing it so the path looks like `<icon src="res/ios/....`

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. The original code generated did **not** have the leading slash and I added that to see if it changed anything. Forgot to take it out before posting the note here. I'm going to edit the original post to remove it to avoid confusion from future readers. And I have re-confirmed that the errors listed above occur without the leading slash (that I removed), too.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like this was changed and you now must add the www folder there, so try this in your top-level config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not put it in the /www folder but in the same project folder as /www. In my Android project, I created a folder called /res/android in the myApp project folder (myApp/res/android/), put all my Android icons there, and they compiled correctly. I imagine that it should work the same way as iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck on this for hours,
it takes sooooo long making all those images exactly the way we want it for each platform
so I need this to be automated at least on compile.
I suppose you can put you phonegap build command in a wrapper script file the quickly corrects the config.xml paths..

What I do for now is quickly open the config.xml file
and run a find and replace :
find `src="res/` to replace with `src="www/res`
also the icon file in the root should be `src="icon.png"` replace with `src="www/icon.png"`.

That's it..compiles perfectly and puts the files all where I need them