# Phonegap doesn't recognize www folder resources

Tags: android, linux, cordova, phonegap-plugins, webstorm

I am new in phonegap development. I have problems with building project on my `Linux` machine. Projects compiles fine on windows machine, but I have following problem

```
cp: no such file or directory: /media/hello/WORK/Development/PhoneGap/phone_gap_app/icon.png
```

But real path is

```
/media/hello/WORK/Development/PhoneGap/phone_gap_app/www/icon.png
```

In my `config.xml` file I have this resource declared like this

```
 <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
```

[image]
It works if add `www` prefix in `config.xml` for each resource.

Please help, how to specify `www` as root directory for project ?

Comment: have you go through http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html ? and if cordova try this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug in phonegap-cli](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/365) itself and also asked in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206902/phonegap-3-5-not-cordova-icons-specified-in-config-xml-not-copied-during-build).
It should not happen from cordova Version 6.2.5+

Try [updating your phonegap cli](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli) using `$ npm install -g phonegap@latest`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I have latest version (